# How does superposition in a quantum register work?

Tags: quantum-state, superposition

When I put each single qubit within a quantum register using Hadamard gates in superposition, how does it work that the whole register quantum-state is in superposition?

On the math-level the register-state is the tensor-product of the single qubit-states; but how is this realized on the physical level? How do the qubits interact?
Looking on entanglement I take a CNOT and I know this gate is realized on the physical level. But what about the tensor-product on the physical level?

Comment: Welcome to QCSE!, could you be more specific on what you mean by "how does it work"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Solovay-Kitaev theorm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solovay%E2%80%93Kitaev_theorem), the Clifford gates (which are generated by $H$, $S$ and $CNOT$), along with a non-Clifford gate - say the $T$ gate, can be used to approximate any unitary down to arbitrary precision.
The state of the register is a pure-state so it can be “reached” using only these gates. Notice that the only 2 qubit gate here is the $CNOT$.

What this implies is that it is enough to physically implement the $CNOT$ gate as the only 2 qubit gate, (as well as the mentioned single qubit gates) to reach the entangled state of both registers.

I hope this andswers your question.